# Fill area between 2 lines (when one is below another)

Tags: python, matplotlib

When this is run, the graph shown does not shade some parts that are below 5. How should I edit it such that it covers the entire area?

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = [4,9,1,3,6,2,4,7,6,3]
z = [5]*len(y)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,z)
plt.fill_between(x,y,z,where=[(y[i]<z[i]) for i in range(len(x))],facecolor='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the comprehension you are using to calculate *where* to fill, you'll notice it only checks at the points listed in your `y` and `z` lists.  However, there are regions *in between* those points that need to be filled as well.

This behavior is mentioned [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html):

> Semantically, `where` is often used for y1 > y2 or similar. By default, the nodes of the polygon defining the filled region will only be placed at the positions in the x array. Such a polygon cannot describe the above semantics close to the intersection. The x-sections containing the intersecion are simply clipped

---

You need `interpolate=True`:

> Setting interpolate to True will calculate the actual intersection point and extend the filled region up to this point

```
plt.fill_between(
    x,y,z,
    where=[(y[i]<z[i]) for i in range(len(x))],
    facecolor='r',
    interpolate=True
)
```

[image]

Since you also asked for a way to avoid having a list of `5`, you may use `axhline` instead, as well as switching your lists to `numpy` arrays for easy comparison:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y = np.array([4,9,1,3,6,2,4,7,6,3])
z = 5

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axhline(y=z, color='orange')
plt.fill_between(x,y,z,where=y<z, facecolor='r', interpolate=True)

plt.show()
```